# Upgrade Magento Version to 2.4.4-p2 - Autoload Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4

Upgraded Magento version to 2.4.4-p2 whenever we move files from local to server even any folder to another folder at same server, shows below error. We do every time vendor folder delete then run composer install command to fix it, but why this happens, please guide us.

**vendor/composer/../thecodingmachine/safe/generated/apache.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/staging_site/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `composer dump-autoload` command instead of `composer install`. This command regenerates the autoload files without installing any new packages, and may help to resolve any issues with the autoload configuration.

Comment: i already try this command but not resolved

Comment: Check that the vendor directory and all of its contents have been uploaded correctly to the server. If any files are missing or corrupt, this could cause issues with the autoload configuration.

Comment: No, all files are fine

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @Sourav